# Get DOM object of input HTML using Node.js

Tags: node.js, dom, html-parsing, npm

I Have a HTML response. I need to parse it and generate a DOM object. After generation of DOM object I need to search a particular string inside it and get complete hierarchy of HTML tags in which it resides. Is there any NPM package available.

Answer (score 7):

There's an even simpler API for this now in htmlparser2:

```
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
var dom = htmlparser.parseDOM("<html>your html string</html>");
console.log(dom);
```

Comment: htmlparser2 seems so badly documented to a newcomer :(

Answer (score 2):

You have [htmlparser2](https://npmjs.org/package/htmlparser2) package that can parse HTML stream. You can get the DOM with [DomHandler](https://npmjs.org/package/domhandler) which is bundled with htmlparser2 itself. See the example given there. E.g.

```
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
var rawHtml = "<html>your html string</html>";
var handler = new htmlparser.DomHandler(function (error, dom) {
        console.log(dom);
});
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
parser.write(rawHtml);
parser.done();
```

Answer (score 1):

Parsing DOM object manually is tedious job.
I think that everyone needs a Soup Select(soupselect package) to parse complex DOM objects.
A soupselect is great package in handling DOM.
See following example:

```
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
var select = require('soupselect').select;
var handler = new htmlparser.DomHandler(function (error, dom) {
  if (error)
    console.log('error:', error);
  else {
    // selector reference:
    // http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp
    var sel = select(dom, 'body p');
    console.log("text in the first <p>: '" + sel[0].children[0].data + "'");
  }
});
var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
var rawHtml =
  "<html>"
  + "<head><title>My Title</title></head>"
  + "<body>"
  + "<p>"
  + "   Hello World"
  + "</p></body></html>";
parser.parseComplete(rawHtml);
```

output:

```
text in the first <p>: '   Hello World'
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseDOM` function is now deprecated in `htmlparser2` package. You can use `parseDocument` function now.

```
const { parseDocument } = require("htmlparser2");

let dom = parseDocument(row_html);
console.log('DOM: ', dom);
```